# Get latest record based on a condition and bi weekly basis in Hive?

Tags: hive, hiveql

Below is a sample data i have in hive table.

```
created_date|   updated_date |  id                  | status
---------------------------------------------------------------
2020-01-07  |    2020-01-07  |  C915524995161427    | HIGH
2020-01-07  |    2020-01-08  |  C915524995161427    | MEDIUM
2020-01-07  |    2020-02-09  |  C915524995161427    | LOW
2020-01-07  |    2020-03-14  |  C915524995161427    | LOW
2020-01-07  |    2020-04-01  |  C915524995161427    | MEDIUM
```

I need to know when was the lastest occurance of a record with status "LOW" on a biweekly basis and also monthly basis
then my expected output is ->

```
id                  |   Biweek | Month
---------------------------------------
C915524995161427    |   6      | 3
```

How do i write a query for this latest biweekly condition in hive?

Comment: what's the start date for biweekly and monthly?

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala i tried select CAST(weekofyear('2020-03-14')/2 AS INT) as biweekly, MONTH('2020-03-14') as month; but i get biweekly as 5 without casting i get 5.5. How can i round it off to 6 ?